# How to remove gameobject from list referencing by raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I I'm trying to create a card game and I have a class called hand, this hand has a `public List<GameObject> cards;` and a methods:

```
public void AddCard(GameObject card)
{
   cards.Add(card);
   GameObject cardObject = Instantiate(card, startPosition, actualCardRotation);
}

public GameObject RemoveCard(GameObject card)
{
        cards.Remove(card);
        return card;
 }
```

then I have a cardGameController attributes `public Hand playerHand, computerHand;` that has a function to select a card for play and call RemoveCard function but its not working here is the code:

```
public void SelectCardToPlay()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 mousePos2D = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);

        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos2D, Vector2.zero);
        if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.CompareTag("Card"))
        {
            Console.text = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Card>().description;

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                playedPlayerCard = playerHand.RemoveCard(hit.collider.gameObject);
                playerSelectedCardBoard.AddCard(playedPlayerCard, 3);

                playedComputerCard = computerHand.PickRandomCard();
                computerSelectedCardBoard.AddCard(playedComputerCard, 3);

                gameState = 5;
            }
        }
    }
```

Seems like the object i get by hit.collider isn't the same as the hand list or something like that, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AddCard you're adding the input card, which I assume is a prefab - since you use it to spawn a new card. I then assume it's this spawned card that you want to remove from the list, since that's probably the object you're hitting?

Simply change your AddCard to:

```
public void AddCard(GameObject card)
{
   GameObject cardObject = Instantiate(card, startPosition, actualCardRotation);
   cards.Add(cardObject);
}
```

And see if that works.

---

If that wasn't the issue, make sure you debug exactly what object it is you're getting att all points. Add some `Debug.Log(gameObject.name);` here and there to see.

Comment: Thanks you were right, I was adding the wrong card to the list